# Prove that a transformation of the identity functor of a Group $G$ (seen as a category) into itself is just an element of the center of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I want to prove the follow:

> Suppose $G$ is a group seen as a category, prove that a transformation of the identity functor of $G$ into itself is just an element of the center of $G$.

I'm not sure if I'm doing well this and I think I'm stuck, can you help me checking? Any corrections are welcome!

-What I have done:

The class of objects of $\mathcal{G}$ (denoted by $\mathcal{A}(G)$) is having only one object: $\{*\}$. So, the transformation of the identity functor of $\mathcal{G}$ into itself is a class of morphisms $\alpha_{*}:*\to *$ $\in\mathcal{G}$ such that $\forall g:*\to*$ the following square commutes:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
* & \stackrel{\alpha_{*}}{\longrightarrow} & * \\
\downarrow{g} & & \downarrow{g} \\
* & \stackrel{\alpha_{*}}{\longrightarrow} & *  
\end{array}$$

i.e. $g\circ\alpha_{*}=\alpha_{*}\circ g$. (Right here I'm stuck!)

P.S. The center of a group $G$ is $Z(G)=\{x\in G | gx=xg\quad\forall g\in G\}$.

Comment: How are you stuck? You have just written precisely the condition that means that $a_{*}$ is in the center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you're almost done... Let $x = \alpha_* : * \to *$, by definition $x$ is an element of $G$ ($\hom_\mathcal{G}(*,*) = G$ by definition). Also by definition, the composition of morphisms $* \to *$ is the product of elements of $G$, so the condition $\alpha_* \circ g = g \circ \alpha_*$ that you have written down means that $xg = gx$, and this is for all $g \in G$. So by definition $x$ is in the center of $G$, because it commutes with all the elements of $G$.

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, if $f,g : G \to H$ are two monoid homomorphisms, considered as functors between one-object categories, a natural transformation $f \to g$ is just an element $h \in H$ such that $h * f(x)=g(x) * h$ for all $x \in G$. Just look at this:

$$\begin{array}{cc} f(\star) & \xrightarrow{h} & g(\star) \\ {\scriptsize f(x)}\downarrow ~~~~&& ~~~~\downarrow {\scriptsize g(x)}\\ f(\star) & \xrightarrow{h} & g(\star) \end{array}$$